# Finding Eclipse Plugin Wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have the following version of Eclipse:

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Kepler Service Release 1

Build id: 20130919-0819

I am trying to use the Plug-In wizard, but when I try to open a new project, this wizard is not one of the options.  I downloaded this standard version of eclipse from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/
Is there something else I have to download or was I supposed to download a different version?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to work with Eclipse Plugin development, you need to use SDK version of Eclipse. You can download Eclipse SDK 4.x from [this link](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse4/)

SDK version contains all the necessary tools to build Eclipse plugins. From the website,

> Developers who use the Eclipse Rich Client Platform (RCP) will find that the Eclipse SDK 4.2 makes it easier to build great looking rich client applications

Comment: Is there any way I could use this version of eclipse? This is my first plug-in and I am trying to use this tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlugIn/article.html  Which is written for the Eclipse standard 4.3.1 package.  (Section 3).

Answer (score 0):

You should have the everything. `File > New > Project...` should open a wizard with `Plug-in Development > Plug-in Project` as one of the wizard selections:

[image: New Wizard]